# How do i access workbench status line manager from a JFace dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

On click of OK button of my JFace dialog i would like to show progress on the workbench status line. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean to Progress indicator section of the status line?

Comment: @greg-449 yes, to the progress indicator section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `Job` (`org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job`) to show progress in the status line progress indicator:

```java
Job job = new MyJob();

job.schedule();


class MyJob extends Job
{
  MyJob()
  {
    super("Job name");
  }

  public IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) 
  {
    monitor.beginTask("Job", workCount);
    try
     {
        ... work
     }
    finally
     {
       monitor.done();
     }

    return Status.OK_STATUS;
  }
}
```

The job runs in the background so will actually run after your dialog closes.

Note: If you use a `Wizard` that has a progress bar at the bottom of the wizard that you can use (how you use this is different).